# Django queries on querysets performance

Tags: django

I have a Model and I am doing a query :

```
my_objects = Model.objects.filter(user = request.user)
```

now over my_objects I am doing :

```
obj = my_objects.get(user = x )
```

I am trying to understand if my **.get** over my_objects will not generate another query to the database and will only work on the filter output ? or it will be generating another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Model` isnt User instance, it will hit database again, because User in that case is a related object, if you dont want hit again the database, use select_related() and filter by yourself `obj`:

> "will automatically "follow" foreign-key relationships, selecting that
>   additional related-object data when it executes its query"

```
my_objects = Model.objects.select_related().filter(user = request.user)
```

see more info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

**EDIT:**
I forgot mention that QuerySet in django are lazy, actually don't hit the db until you evaluate the queryset, these are methods that force to evaluate a queryset : 
[methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Comment: What will happens if my first .filter was (user = request.user) but my second .get is on a different non-related object ? will it hit the db again ?

Comment: yes, you are creating another queryset, is best that filter object by youself
new_obj = [obj for obj in my_objects if obj.some_value == "some_value"]
this is better than let django ORM filter objects for you.

See my edit

Comment: but you can nest filters, queryset.filter().filter() for example.